# Indexing and execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I understood that a Clustered Index determines the physical order of data in a table.So i created 2 temp tables to check the physical ordering of records.

```
CREATE TABLE #My_table_1
  (
     ID   INT,
     COL1 INT,
     COL2 VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
     COL3 VARCHAR(20)
  );

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Employee
  ON #My_table_1 (ID, COL1 DESC)

INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (1,10,'10','10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (2,520,'20','10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (3,50,'30','10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (5,55,'65','10');    
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (1,5,'100','10');            
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (3,300,'50','10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (3,40,'5','10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (1,15,'4','10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_1 VALUES (5,100,'56','10');

CREATE TABLE #My_table_2
  (
     ID   INT,
     COL1 INT,
     COL2 VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
  ) 

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Employee
  ON #My_table_2 (ID, COL1 DESC) --Creating a CLUSTERED INDEX on columns ID,COL1

INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (1,10,'10');
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (2,520,'20');
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (3,50,'30');
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (5,55,'65'); 
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (1,5,'100');         
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (3,300,'50');
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (3,40,'5');
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (1,15,'4');
INSERT INTO #My_table_2 VALUES (5,100,'56');
```

As i querying the both the tables, i found ordering of records are different in both the tables. Why it is so?
[Selection_Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqdMa.jpg)
So i checked the execution plan, for the queries execution plans are different.
[image: Execution Plan]
Can anyone explain,why it is happening? Whether my understanding about Clustered index is wrong?

Comment: How did you determine ordering? Because the select does not give you order , it gives you results in an order as the SQL Server sees fit. If you want an order, add an order by clause.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your understanding of clustered indices is spot on.  It's your understanding of the SQL Server optimizer, statistics, and ordering that's at play here.

The query optimizer will feel free to ignore any index (even hinted indices) if it decides that it has a better method.  That better method is determined using a variety of information - which entire books cover - about selectivity of data, types of data, size of tables, number of columns, etc.  Even for a clustered index only the specified data is kept in the index; lookups still have to occur for the remaining columns of data.  What's the cost of looking up those individual columns of data versus just doing a table scan?

Finally, that data is not guaranteed to be returned in any order, ever.  It may coincidentally match up with the physical order when a clustered index is used, but that's not intentional.  It's a side effect.  The only way to return data in a known ordered fashion is to use ORDER BY.